# define custom array in route using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In previous version of Laravel 5 we define extra or custom array in route along multi middleware like below:

```
Route::get('/user_list',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@index',
    'as' =>'user_list',
    middleware' => ['auth','roles'],
    'roles' => ['Administrator', 'Operator']
   ]);
```

However, in Laravel 8 it gives error and I defined like below:
as it gives error on 'uses'.
But below syntax is not belong to Laravel 8.

```
Route::get('/user_list',array(
        'uses'=>'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index',
        'as' =>'user_list',
        'middleware' => ['auth','roles'],
        'roles' => ['Administrator', 'Operator'])
);
```

My Main Question is to define custom array in route as per Laravel 8.

```
Route::get('user_list',[UserController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth','roles'])
    ->name('user_list');
```

This above code works fine but I need to define an custom array in order to check the role
**`'roles' => ['Administrator', 'Operator']`**

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
Route::get('user_list',[UserController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth','roles','role:Administrator|Operator'])
    ->name('user_list');
```

Comment: you bind in middleware array, I want to pass separate array in order to compare from my middleware class. That wasn't work.

Comment: this solution work for me somehow, as I have to explode it and separate the option in order to check the role. It will be good if any one can let me know the define another array/parameter or anything

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define it about all routes and use it like this

```
$roles= ['uses'=>'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index',
        'as' =>'user_list',
        'middleware' => ['auth','roles'],
        'roles' => ['Administrator', 'Operator']];

Route::get('/user_list', function () use ($roles) {   
    return anything;
});
```

Comment: its a same syntax as Laravel 5